# How to pass backslashes argument to a script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I just want to append an user input argument in a text file. I'm using the following command:

```
echo "$2" >> "./db.txt"
```

`$2` is expected to user to set a path like: `D:\Projects\MyProject`. It writes to the file, but with no backslashes. The result is:

> D:ProjectsMyProject

I can't find anywhere how to fix that. I've tried using `-e` or `-E` params([taken from here](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html)) but it doesn't seems to make difference in this case.

Comment: Could it be that `$2` *never* contains those backslashes? How do you invoke your script?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `echo`. post complete code.

Comment: @Biffen it should be called as `./script.sh D:\Projects/MyProjects`. It is mandatory, there is checkings on that.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Those backslashes will indeed disappear. Try to quote the command line argument, e.g. `./script.sh 'D:\Projects/MyProjects'`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, single quoting it in args will escape those backslashes

Comment: @Mox sure, know I know that, ty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape backslashes in the shell: `\\`, or put the string in quotes.

For debugging purposes use `set -x`.

Comment: There is no way to avoid that and parse in the code? Imo its not nice to ask user to escape it by himself.

Comment: Well, quotes would do, I think.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown If the backslashes aren't quoted or escaped on the command line, they'll be removed before the parameter is passed to your script. Once they're gone, there's no way to put them back. Therefore, they *must* be euoted or escaped on the command line.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you and I voted up your comments 
 (backslashes are removed before the param is passed to scripts), but could you please provide some document citations? I tried to search for an authoritative source but failed.

Answer (score 1):

`echo 'foo\bar\baz'` will show `foo\bar\baz`

When using no quotes at all for your arguments, some characters have special meaning , for example `$` means variable as in `$HOME`. Space is the argument separator, so if you want to pass it as one argument, you have to escape that too.

You can use [strong quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#strong_quoting) to not have to quote the backslaches (for example`'foo\bar'`) . Inside strong-quoted strings, the only character which has special meaning is `'`, which means that it is the only character that has to be escaped if you want to put it into a screen.

So  `echo 'foo\bar\baz'` will show `foo\bar\baz`

Comment: You cannot include a single quote in a single-quoted string, even if it is escaped. `echo 'foo\''` is a syntax error.